# BigQuery for large datasets that get updates periodically - deleting the older records by id

Tags: google-bigquery

In my very beginner research, it seems like doing large data record updates in BQ if frowned upon and that completely adding the new records then deleing the older records is preferred.

Sounds fine.  I have searched this and found a lot of examples of deleting duplicate records where I assume the entire record is exactly the same.

I don't want that, I want to delete older records where a newer version of the same ID is present.

Think voter data with all voters in a region.  Tens of thousands or records.  The county keeps a unique voter_id in their dataset.

What I want is to insert the new update data set and then delete all older records where there is a newer version of voter_id.

Can anyone please share the best way to accomplish this in BQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to upsert? I would suggest reading this documentation about CDC in [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/change-data-capture#upsert-delete-example) (Change data capture). You would stream table updates with cdc.

But in terms of Query I think [Merge](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) is the way to go as it can combine DMLs (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) statements.

Sample (Found in the documentation):

```
MERGE dataset.DetailedInventory T
USING dataset.Inventory S
ON T.product = S.product
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND quantity < 20 THEN
  INSERT(product, quantity, supply_constrained, comments)
  VALUES(product, quantity, true, ARRAY<STRUCT<created DATE, comment STRING>>[(DATE('2016-01-01'), 'comment1')])
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(product, quantity, supply_constrained)
  VALUES(product, quantity, false)
```